Correlation between CDB instances, PDB and Host CPU
Exadata CPU allocation question: I am running 4 CDB instances each of them contain same PDB. Instance 1 at peak uses 12 cores, 2 - 5, 3 - 8, 4 - 10. The host has 96 cores. How many cores can be returned? 84 or 96 - (12+5+8+4)= 67. In other words, provided all instances are running simultaneously, how many cores would I need to have on the Host?
